# Multi php version not working with 7.1.4

Tags: php, apache

apache and php

- D:\webserver\Apache24
- D:\webserver\php\php-5.6.30-Win32-VC11-x64
- D:\webserver\php\php-7.0.18-Win32-VC14-x64
- D:\webserver\php\php-7.1.4-Win32-VC14-x64

three sites

- D:\wwwroot\tests\php56
- D:\wwwroot\tests\php70
- D:\wwwroot\tests\php71

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
ScriptAlias /php-7.1.4/ "D:/webserver/php/php-7.1.4-Win32-VC14-x64/"
ScriptAlias /php-7.0.18/ "D:/webserver/php/php-7.0.18-Win32-VC14-x64/"
ScriptAlias /php-5.6.30/ "D:/webserver/php/php-5.6.30-Win32-VC11-x64/"

<Directory "D:/webserver/php">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "D:/wwwroot">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\wwwroot\tests\php56"
    ServerName php56.local
    ErrorLog "logs/php56-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/php56-access.log" common
    <Directory "D:\wwwroot\tests\php56">
        Action application/x-httpd-php "/php-5.6.30/php-cgi.exe"
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\wwwroot\tests\php70"
    ServerName php70.local
    ErrorLog "logs/php70-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/php70-access.log" common
    <Directory "D:\wwwroot\tests\php70">
        Action application/x-httpd-php "/php-7.0.18/php-cgi.exe"
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\wwwroot\tests\php71"
    ServerName php71.local
    ErrorLog "logs/php71-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/php71-access.log" common
    <Directory "D:\wwwroot\tests\php71">
        Action application/x-httpd-php "/php-7.1.4/php-cgi.exe"
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Open browser, visit:
1. http://php56.local/phpinfo.php
2. http://php70.local/phpinfo.php
3. http://php71.local/phpinfo.php
1 and 2 are ok. Only php 7.1.4 always Internal Server Error.

Why?

Comment: Is there any additional info in the ErrorLog(s)? I assume the test sites are identical? Are there any .htaccess files in there?

Comment: No .htaccess, only phpinfo.php. Error log: 
malformed header from script 'php-cgi.exe': Bad header: <br />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found where the problem is.

The two php versions which are ok, have no php.ini, I didn't deal with it. Maybe some default values is used.

The php version which can't work, I copied php.ini-development to be php.ini, but didn't change extension_dir.

After I set
extension_dir = "D:/webserver/php/php-7.1.4-Win32-VC14-x64/ext"
All works.